# How do I print a whole array up to the point which I have reached (Visual Basic)?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm making a dice game and I want to print all of the previous dice outputs using an array, but I'm not sure how I would actually go around printing the array, bearing in mind I'm not actually sure if I've even properly done the array. I have pasted all of my code below.

```
    Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim amountrolls(100) As Integer
        Dim cash As Integer = 1
        For i As Integer = 1 To 100


            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to roll the dice ?")
            Dim YorN As String = Console.ReadLine

            If (YorN = "no") Or (YorN = "No") Then
                Console.WriteLine("You won £" & cash)
                Console.ReadLine()
            Else

                While (YorN = "yes") Or (YorN = "Yes")
                    Randomize()
                    Dim roll As Integer = (Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))

                    Select Case roll
                        Case 1
                            amountrolls(i) = roll
                            Console.WriteLine("You rolled a 1 and lost all your money!!")
                            cash = 0
                            Console.WriteLine("you have £" & cash)
                            Console.WriteLine("Do you still want to play?")
                            YorN = Console.ReadLine
                        Case 2, 3, 4
                            amountrolls(i) = roll
                            Console.WriteLine("You rolled a " & roll & " so nothing happened.")
                            cash = cash
                            Console.WriteLine("you have £" & cash)
                            Console.WriteLine("Do you still want to play?")
                            YorN = Console.ReadLine
                        Case 5, 6
                            amountrolls(i) = roll
                            Console.WriteLine("You rolled a " & roll & " and doubled your money!!")
                            cash = cash * 2
                            Console.WriteLine("you have £" & cash)
                            Console.WriteLine("Do you still want to play?")
                            YorN = Console.ReadLine
                    End Select

                End While

            End If
            Console.WriteLine(amountrolls())
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("You have £" & cash)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(amountrolls(i))`?

Comment: Or after the loop: `amountrolls.ToList().ForEach(Function(x) Console.WriteLine(x))`

Comment: Is this homework? If it's not - or it is but you don't to to do it that way - don't use an array and don't generate random numbers that way. Use a `List(Of Integer)`, which will start empty and actually grow as you add items to it. That way, you just get the entire list every time, instead of worrying about which array elements you've set and which you haven't. As for random numbers, use the `Random` class. If you are going to generate random numbers that way, at least do it properly, i.e. call `Randomize` once and once only.

Comment: Also, arrays are zero-based so treat them that way. Ignoring the zero index is just bad. You specify the upper bound, mot the length, when you create an array. If you want an array with 100 elements then you specify 99 as the upper bound. You then index it from 0 to 99.

Answer (score 1):

Use one instance of the .net `Random` class. As suggested in comments we use a `List(Of T)` instead of an array. When we ask the user yes or no, give them a clue what you want them to enter. I called `.ToLower` so I only have to check for the lower case. There is more you can do to check user input here but this is enough for now.

We use the `.Next` method of the `Random` class. This will return a number 1 or greater and less than 7. Simply `.Add` the number to the list.

If the user rolls a 1, he is done. He will never get more than zero with your rules so we exit the While loop.

You have repeated the same code in each `Case` of the `Select Case` so I moved the duplicate code to after the select.

When the user enters n, the loop does not continue and the final results are displayed with a `For Each` for every entry in the list.

```
Private Rnd As New Random

Sub Main()
    Dim amountrolls As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim cash As Integer = 1

    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to roll the dice? (y or n ")
    Dim YorN As String = Console.ReadLine.ToLower

    If (YorN = "n") Then
        End
    Else
        While (YorN = "y")
            Dim roll As Integer = Rnd.Next(1, 7)
            amountrolls.Add(roll)
            Select Case roll
                Case 1
                    Console.WriteLine("You rolled a 1 and lost all your money!!")
                    cash = 0
                    Exit While
                Case 2, 3, 4
                    Console.WriteLine("You rolled a " & roll & " so nothing happened.")
                Case 5, 6
                    Console.WriteLine("You rolled a " & roll & " and doubled your money!!")
                    cash = cash * 2
            End Select
            Console.WriteLine("you have £" & cash)
            Console.WriteLine("Do you still want to play? (y or n)")
            YorN = Console.ReadLine.ToLower
        End While
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("These are all your rolls.")
    For Each i In amountrolls
        Console.WriteLine(i)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("You have £" & cash)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```